# LaTeX error : use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition - TinyTex in R?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

I'm using the tiny_tex package in R to generate a LaTeX document from a .Rnw file (Sweave) - I can produce basic LaTeX outputs, however when trying to make something more complex with the color.sty package I get this error:

```
Error: color.sty:251: Use of \@startpbox doesn't match it's definition. 
Error: color.sty: ==> Fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced!
```

Can anyone make sense of this error message, the color.sty file exists and is the latest package.

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem.